# Force redirect from Http to Https

Tags: node.js, ssl, https

I have a website with a hostname like **mydomain.com.au**. When I hit that in URL it is automatically redirecting to **http://mydomain.com.au/main**. But it should be redirected to **https://mydomain.com.au/main**. But when I hit like mydomain.com.au:portno it is redirecting to **https://mydomain.com.au/main**. Is there any possibility to redirect to HTTPS without entering port no?

Here is the code that uses to redirect

```
app.use('*',function(request, response,next) {

//if(!request.secure){
    response.redirect('https://mydomain.com.au/main');
    console.log(request.secure)
    console.log(request.protocol)
//}


next();
```

})

Answer (score 2):

It's better to configure redirect on virtual server, than in your app code. Usually you can do it .htaccess file, nginx or apache.

You have to listen port and than redirect all requests to https.

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

**nginx**

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

**apache**

```
NameVirtualHost *:80в
&lt;VirtualHost *:80&gt;
ServerName www.yourdomain.com
Redirect / https://www.yourdomain.com/
&lt;/VirtualHost&gt;
```